# facet_wrap: using x_free scale but having only 2 different x-axis with date

Tags: axis-labels, facet-wrap

I performed on three sites in two different periods messurements. Now i want to show the results using facet_wrap. Here I want to have 2 columns (first line first period, secound line secound period) and each site in a row. To have only the respective dates in the respective graph, I use x_free, resulting in the desired graph. Now I would like to delete the X axis labels in the above graphs so that the date is only visible in the last graph.

My data looks like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8owij.png)

My code for the plots is this one:

```
test_data$date <- as.Date(test_data$date )

Boxes <- ggplot(test_data, aes(date, number_bats)) + 
  geom_col(aes(date,number_bats)) +
  facet_wrap(~Box, ncol = 2, scales = "free_x")

print(Boxes)
```

and the resulting graph looks like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URqJ7.png)

How can I now delete the dates in the first two graphs, but keep it in the last one?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found this package "ggh4x" with an extended facet function (facet_grid2 and facet_wrap2) which solved my problem.